# Dynamic Height for Tableview Cell Containing another table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on Table view which again contains three tableviews in a single cell. Now I want to set the Height of Each table view Dynamic. None of the inner tableview should scroll. It should take the height as the total number of rows present inside it. Below is the Image of the UI I have achieved till now.

Here it has three tableviews. Top left with FRT rows, Top Right with Flwr rows and bottom one with City rows.
All this table views are contained in outer tableview cell.

I want to make height of all the tableviews dynamic i.e height based on the number of rows it contains even for outermost tableview.

[image]

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: First thing using tableview inside tableViewCell is not recommendable from Apple, You should use here UICollectionView with customLayout. In case you want to use tableView inside tableViewCell then inner tableView scrolling set as false use autolayout for dynamic height for cell.

Comment: Actually Before working on Nested Tableviews I was working on the same approach just like you have mentioned. But at one point I got stuck with that so I moved to Nested Tableview approach.

Comment: This is not correct approach you will face many issues further so try to collection view and resolved issue. tableView inside tableViewCell is not right way.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate nested tableView's height.

```
tableView.contentSize.height // This return height
```

and on the outer tableView's delegate set tableView cell height to calculated nested tableview's height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
    if let nestedTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NestedTableViewCell {
        let heightNestedTableView = nestedTableViewCell.nestedTableView.contentsize.height
        return heightNestedTableView
    } else {
        return 0
    } }
```